# What's the difference between the output of the following concurrent Scala programs

Tags: multithreading, scala, concurrency, future

```scala
// First
import concurrent.Future
import concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
for {
  _ <- Future { Thread.sleep(3000); println("a") }
  _ <- Future { Thread.sleep(2000); println("b") }
  _ <- Future { Thread.sleep(1000); println("c") }
} {} 

// Second
 import concurrent.Future
import concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
val future1 = Future { Thread.sleep(3000); println("a") }
val future2 = Future { Thread.sleep(2000); println("b") }
val future3 = Future { Thread.sleep(1000); println("c") }
for {
  _ <- future1
  _ <- future2
  _ <- future3
} {}
```

Comment: First program will run the three `Futures` **Sequentially** _(meaning one after the previous finishes)_. While the second will run the three **Concurrently** _(meaning all three will start at the same time)_. - Anyways, this sounds like a interview question, as you can easily had checked that just by running the snippets and a few google searches.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the command below to have a better understanding of what Scala compiler do under the hood:

```
$ scalac -Xprint:typer MainClass.scala
```

'First' will be desugared into:

```
    scala.concurrent.Future.apply[Unit]({
      java.lang.Thread.sleep(3000L); scala.Predef.println("a")
    })(scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global)
      .foreach[Unit](((_: Unit) =>
      scala.concurrent.Future.apply[Unit]({
        java.lang.Thread.sleep(2000L); scala.Predef.println("b")
      })(scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global)
        .foreach[Unit](((_: Unit) => scala.concurrent.Future.apply[Unit]({
        java.lang.Thread.sleep(1000L); scala.Predef.println("c")
      })(scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global)
        .foreach[Unit](((_: Unit) => ()))(scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global)))(scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global)))
    (scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global);
```

'Second' into

```
    val future1: scala.concurrent.Future[Unit] = scala.concurrent.Future.apply[Unit]({
      java.lang.Thread.sleep(3000L);
      scala.Predef.println("a")
    })(scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global);
    val future2: scala.concurrent.Future[Unit] = scala.concurrent.Future.apply[Unit]({
      java.lang.Thread.sleep(2000L);
      scala.Predef.println("b")
    })(scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global);
    val future3: scala.concurrent.Future[Unit] = scala.concurrent.Future.apply[Unit]({
      java.lang.Thread.sleep(1000L);
      scala.Predef.println("c")
    })(scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global);
    {
      future1.flatMap[Unit](((_: Unit) => future2.flatMap[Unit](((_: Unit) => future3.map[Unit](((_: Unit) => ()))(scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global)))(scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global)))(scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global);
      ()
    }
```

In 'First' case the next Future will be created inside the '.foreach' of the first Future and so on.

In 'Second' case all 3 futures will be created first, executed in parallel and then flatMap'ped.

Answer (score 1):

Since the for expression is `desugared` to a series of nested `flatMap`/`map` calls, the `Future` instances in the first examples will run sequentially.

While the code in the second example will, depending on the `ExecutionContext` in scope, run the `Future` instances in parallel.

Another thing to keep in mind is that scala Futures are strict, which means that you can't separate `Future` definition from its execution. You can read about this and other `Future` weaknesses here:

[Scala Futures vs Monix Tasks](http://www.beyondthelines.net/programming/futures-vs-tasks/)